# Android Dynamic content in webview

Tags: android, iframe, webview, dynamic-content

I have a dynamic content Iframe like this:

[image: CountDown Timer]

But the webview does not show the count down, only show a static image Until you re-enter the activity or reload the data manually, in this case the webview blinks every reload.

this is my code:

```
String html = "<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/countdown/i5nxrd9z/n1440/cf100/cm0/cu4/ct0/cs0/ca0/co0/cr0/ss0/cac000/cpc000/pc009/tcfff/fn3/fs130/szw256/szh108/iso2017-04-08T15:30:00" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="256" height="108"></iframe>";

 timeshower = (WebView) tournmentview.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
 timeshower.loadData(html);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to set the Settings for the WebView (particularly setJavaScriptEnabled()). For example:

```
    final WebSettings settings = timeshower.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Simple and clear, thanks for the help it works great!